Laravel 11 response Access-Control-Allow-Origin is still a wildcard (*)
No matter how i try to confirgue cors, from config/cors.php with the following settings:
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['https://example.co.uk', '*.example.co.uk', 'example.co.uk'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];

My frontend is example.co.uk, with my backend api.example.co.uk.
I'm using nuxt 3 on my frontend, but still when i inspect the response, i see
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
with error on my console:
Access to fetch at 'https://api.example.co.uk/api/user' from origin 'https://example.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
I have tried literally everything i see online, but nothing seems to work
I have tried literally everything i see online, but nothing seems to work

You should check whether your web server ( Apache, nginx, caddy, etc ) is overriding the header set by laravel

Also worth doing a php artisan config:cache or a php artisan config:clear after making changes to env/config

How do I check this on Apache web server please?

I have ran the config:cache and even the config:clear command a million times
